# How to print the current theme name in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles

We can use `getTheme()` inside an activity to get the current theme. But how I can print the name of this retrieved theme?

There are no method such as `getTheme().getName()`. I tried using `resolveAttribute` and `obtainStyledAttributes`, with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
int theme = 0;
try 
{
String packageName = getClass().getPackage().getName();
PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
theme = packageInfo.applicationInfo.theme;
}
 catch (Exception e) 
{ 
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It's retrieving 0 as result. From javadoc: _A style resource identifier (in the package's resources) of the default visual theme of the application. From the "theme" attribute or, ** if not set, 0** _. But, the app must be using some theme.. Right? Maybe from system or from the android version set as target?

Comment: This will only return the name of the theme that was set in the Manifest.xml - it will not return the name of the activity theme